# How to delete string [] arrays from another string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

First I define my string array and a string from which I want to remove words:

```
string[] excludeWords = {"word1","word2","word3","word4","word5"}
   
    string sentence = "word1 word2 word5 marble1";

    TextBox1.Text = sentence;
```

I want to remove excludeWords from sentence so I want this output in my textbox(ASP.NET):

```
marble1
```

I tried Except method but not removes the words:

```
string filteredText = sentence.Except(excludeWords);

TextBox1.Text = filteredText
```

What method should I use?

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = excludeWords.Except(sentence.Split(" ")).ToArray();
TextBox1.Text = string.Join(" ", result);
```

result:

> "word3 word4"

[image]

You edited the question. In this case, you can use the following code

```
        string[] excludeWords = { "word1", "word2", "word3", "word4", "word5" };
        string sentence = "word1 word2 word5 marble1";
        var result = sentence.Split(" ").Except(excludeWords).ToArray();
        textBox1.Text= string.Join(" ", result);
```

result:

> marble1

Comment: this does not work; it gives error can not convert string to chart...

Comment: @user20465780 I added an image to the answer so you can see the result

Comment: @user20465780 Be careful not to put `'` instead of `"`.

Comment: sorry apologize I made a mistake I want an output where excludeWords deletes elements what sentence contains if it match; I reedited the post...

Comment: @user20465780 I edited the answer for the new state of the question